python, pywinrm. ошибка при работе из под системы
всем привет.
собственно такая проблема, имеем код(под сообщением) подключение к winrm серверу и выполнение команды. код скомпилирован с помощью pyinstaller в .exe приложение. нужно чтоб приложение запускалось с помощью планировщика задач с периодичностью в час, отправляло на сервер команду по средствам winrm и завершалось. все отлично работает, подключается если запустить приложение просто двойным щелчком пользователя, НО когда же приложение выполняется от имени системы(хоть планировщик задач, хоть как служба при помощи nssm.exe) то при подключении к серверу выдает ошибку: SpnegoError (4294967295): [WinError -2146893043] The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized, Context: Processing security token
понимаю что скорее всего где то проблема в пользовательском пк, какая то настройка скорее всего, ведь из под юзера работает, из под системы нет.
подскажите пожалуйста кто может как и куда смотреть, возможно как исправить.
код:
    import winrm

    try:
        host = 'http://192.168.1.110:5985'
        box1 = winrm.Session(host,
                             auth=("admin", "password"),
                             transport='ntlm',
                             server_cert_validation='ignore',
                             read_timeout_sec='6',
                             operation_timeout_sec='5')
        stat = box1.run_cmd('echo net')
        print(str(stat.std_out))
    except Exception as ex:
        print(str(ex))


на деле все оказалось просто.
при работе от имени пользователя в строку авторизации автоматически подставляется домен по умолчанию, даже если компьютер не находится в домене, а при работе от имени системы домен не подставлялся и аутентификация не проходила, так как недостаточно данных для неё.
добавил
auth=("WORKGROUP\\admin", "password")

и все заработало:)
